# Coding dojos on regular basis

Tags: programming-practices

Do you find reasonable to practice coding dojos on a regular basis? I understand dojo may be a good starting point to introduce somebody to some approach but what is the point of making  similar dojos regularly?

So currently we have two teams which are working on real project written in TDD. One team wants to work on TDD-oriented dojos regularly and other prefers to practice it only on real tasks. Who is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both are. Teams should determine their own working rules and guidelines. If one wants to practice techniques (e.g. TDD) in real tasks, let them. If another prefers to practice in tasks that are designed to sharpen TDD skills, but aren't applicable to the project, let them.

If one team wanted to do daily stand-ups where they went around the room in clockwise fashion and the other wanted to use a token that got tossed to the next person to speak, would you try to make one team right and the other wrong?